# Paste multiple filtered criteria into one sheet without pasting over the original data?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble copying filtered data on the criteria range, then pasting it into the P&L Regulated Entities sheet without having the new filtered data paste over the previous filtered data. How can I adjust the code below to ensure that data filtered on 1226 is pasted first, then the data filtered on 1843 is pasted below the data from 1226?

```
Sheets("P&L").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1226*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False,Transpose:=False


Sheets("P&L").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1843*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("P&L").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*865*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("P&L").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1223*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Well you would want to make the Range("A1").Select dynamic by finding the last row that has data and moving down one.  See here for methods on finding the last row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba then add 1 to the return of the last row.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you show how I would incorporate that into the code above?

Comment: Also, it's best to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). A lot of this code can be whittled down to maybe 10 lines max.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this. The `With...End With` structure allows you to drops the `.Select` statements. The line like `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)` will put the copied data in the first empty row on the Regulated Entities sheet.

```
With Sheets("P&L")
   .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1226*"
   .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
End With

With Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False,Transpose:=False
End With


With Sheets("P&L")
   .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1843*"
   .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
End With

With Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities")
   .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With


With Sheets("P&L")
   .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*865*"
   .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
End With

With Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities")
   .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With


With Sheets("P&L")
   .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1223*"
   .AutoFilter.Range.Copy
End With

With Sheets("P&L Regulated Entities")
   .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```